# EC2 User-data, specific command not executing on start, works fine manually

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I searched for this prior to submitting but couldn't find anything.

I have a bash scrip that runs with my EC2 instances (ubuntu AMI)
The final command saves the IP address as a variable - this seems to have 'suddenly' (read recently) stopped working. It's like it ignores the commands altogether.

If I manually copy paste the command in it works fine however (but that defeats the point)

Script

```
#!/bin/bash

# update the install on the ubuntu image
sudo apt-get update -y

# install Docker's certificate etc
sudo apt-get install \
apt-transport-https \
ca-certificates \
curl \
software-properties-common

# add dockers official GPG key
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key  add -

# set up the stable repository
 sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"

# update again now with added repo
sudo apt-get update -y

# Install Docker CE 
sudo apt-get install docker-ce -y

# install docker-compose (in case you need to make a docker-compose file)
sudo apt-get install docker-compose -y

# make docker group if not already created
sudo groupadd docker

# make ubuntu user part of docker group
sudo usermod -aG docker ubuntu

# create results dir
mkdir /home/ubuntu/mount

# change permissions on mount drive so all users can read/write
sudo chmod 775 /home/ubuntu/mount

# change ownership of mount folder so that files can be sent to it
sudo chown -R ubuntu /home/ubuntu/mount/

# install htop 
sudo apt install htop

#set ip as env var
IP=$(hostname -i)
```

This doesn't save the IP address as a variable, like I said it's fine if I manually copy past it into the command line after the fact.

I'm running this from within the EC2 console on AWS. Under the User Data section within Advanced Details.

What appears to happen is that the following command is not being run:

```
IP=$(hostname -i)
```

I ssh onto the instance and call 'echo $IP' and get nothing. however if I manually run the 'IP=$(hostname -i)' command it populates the variable with the current IP address.

### UPDATE

I've now moved my script to GitHub: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ScreamingJoypad/jmeter-armada/master/userdata.sh

Running each command on the instance individually works fine, as does creating the script from within the instance after it's created

However using `curl -o <filename>.sh <link>` and then running `. <filename>.sh` does not work and offers the below error:

[image]

Comment: In what hook are running this script? And where is the part where you use fail to use IP?

Comment: Updated the question, please let me know if that helps :-)

Comment: @MikeSmith: If you execute the script on your instance, the variable `IP` won't be exported, since it is defined in a sub-shell. Are you not sourcing this script?

Comment: @Inian - You'll need to be patient with me, I'm new to all of this :-)
So, when you say 'sourcing the script' do you mean running it as a standalone .sh from within the instance? If so then no, I'm simply either copy-pasting the script into the Admin console on AWS or I'm referencing it when launching from the command line on my local.

I'm confused as this command has worked in the past as part of the user-data level

Comment: @MikeSmith: So this is how it is, you have an interpreter set explicitly `#!/bin/bash` set in script. So the shell launches a separate sub-shell to run the script (however it is triggered from), all the variables defined and exported are in the scope of this child shell and once the script exits, the sub-shell environment along with its variables are lost. But sourcing the script ( `source <scriptname>` or `. <scriptname>`) runs the script in _current_ shell so all variables are retained in the parent shell.

Comment: Update: Transferred my 'perform all the things' script to GitHub:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ScreamingJoypad/jmeter-armada/master/userdata.sh
- Running commands one by one = works  
- Starting instance, creating a .sh file with the raw from that link and then running `. Filename.sh` = works
- Starting instance and the running `curl -o filename.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ScreamingJoypad/jmeter-armada/master/userdata.sh` and then `. Filename.sh` = Does not work
- Running the above within the Advanced Settings of the AWS console = Not yet tried (as manual method didn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter the last line of your script to

```
 echo "export IP=$(hostname -i)" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

That makes the `IP` variable available in bash shells - which seems to be what you want

Comment: :-D

I believe this may have worked, I'm going to perform some more testing against it and then update the question. Thank you for the tip! (I'm really excited that this might be solved)

Comment: It works! I've just tested it with a spot fleet on AWS and each of them responded as I wanted. Thank you @Vorsprung this has made my day!

Answer (score 2):

Just some help to get you started.

Variables created in one shell are not available in another.

Its possible to start up a new shell that keeps it by using export where it is started.

```
help export
```

It is possible to run the script in your current shell using source.

```
help source
```

It is possible to run commands and set the variable automatically when you log in.

```
man bash #look for 'bashrc'.
```

Comment: Hey @mncl - thanks for the tips. I tried using `export IP` after the troublesome command but it didn't work. I'm going to persevere however and see if I can maybe download the script as part of the instance starting then invoke that script.